# templateName as computed property

Tags: ember.js

According to the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/inserting-views-in-templates/) it is possible to specify a template for a view with `templateName`:

```
App.ShowEntryView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'my-template',
});
```

And we can use it like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div>
    {{view App.ShowEntryView}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Could we bind the `templateName` to another property? Something like:

```
    {{view App.ShowEntryView templateNameBinding="myComputedTemplateName"}}
```

So that in the controller we have:

```
myComputedTemplateName: function() {
    return "this-is-my-template-name";
}.property()
```

The reason why I want to do this is that I have several models which I am displaying as an heterogeneous table. I want that, whenever the user selects one of the entries in the table, a detailed view is shown, using the right template according to the underlying model.

Comment: You could use partials instead, which allow for dynamic template names in handlebars, in the view's template. So the view's `templateName` property is static and the template's content is `{{partial view.someDynamicNameProperty}}`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do this:

`{{view App.ShowEntryView templateName=myComputedTemplateName}}`

[JS Bin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/deqovu/5/edit)